# Should the space-history and history tags be merged?

Tags: discussion

"space-history" is little used, showing up 4 times.  "history" has ~ 200 appearances.

Perhaps "space-history" is redundant given the nature of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merged and synonymized. You are correct that we should be careful about using the prefix "space" in tags here. In most cases, it is redundant.

Comment: All the other tags prefixed by "space-" looks fine:
space-shuttle, space-race, space-program, space-dust, space-art, space-telescope, space-station, space-elevator, space-weather, space-tether, space-track and space-gun.

Comment: Agreed, but we should be careful with new tags